# How to authorize multiple paypal account for future payment?

Tags: android, paypal

in my Android application I want to use paypal for payment and user will login once and will pay any time without login when it want for that I am using following code of paypal SDK

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT);
```

and receiving auth code in onActivityResult like this

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        PayPalAuthorization auth = data
                .getParcelableExtra(PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
        if (auth != null) {
            try {
                Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", auth.toJSONObject()
                        .toString(4));
                String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", authorization_code);
                sendAuthorizationToServer(auth);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Future Payment code received from PayPal",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("FuturePaymentExample",
                        "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
            }
        }
```

and doing further process to payment up to this I have no any problem.
But now I want to give option to users that they can set more than one paypal account and at time of pay app will ask them to choose an account from which they want to pay from their saved accounts.
is it possible please suggest me better idea.